# Prove that if $[a_1, b_1] \supset [a_2, b_2] \supset ... \supset [a_n b_n] , $ then $ \exists x_n : x_n \in [a_i, b_i], 1 \leq i \leq n$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Eventually, the lengths of the intervals as n approaches infinity converge to 0, becoming infinitely smaller.

That is, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, lim $|b_i-a_i|$ = 0

Note: $[a_n, b_n]$ is the superset of all $[a_i,b_i]$

The property states that there is a single value, $x_n$, that which is contained in all of them

This seems intuitively true, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: This is [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem).

Comment: @eminem, how do I go about proving it?

Comment: The link provided by @eminem already contains a proof. However, if you are not familiar with topology, my favourite beginners book in real-analysis, "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle and Sherbert contains a proof of Cantor's intersection theorem using nothing more than real analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$. Notice that $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subseteq [a_1,b_1]$, so the sequence is bounded by $b_1$. Now $[a_{k+1}, b_{k+1}] \subseteq [a_k, b_k]$ meaning that $a_k \leq a_{k+1}$, so the sequence is monotone. A bounded monotone sequence converges to something, so $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_k = x_0$, where $x_0 \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty [a_k, b_k]$. Suppose $x_1$ is also in the intersection. Then $d(x_0, x_1) \leq |b_k - a_k|$ for all $k$, and since this distance goes to $0$ we have $d(x_0, x_1) = 0$. Therefore we must have $x_1 = x_0$. So there is a unique point in this intersection.

Comment: Note that the fact $x_0 \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty [a_k,b_k]$ isn't necessarily obvious, but I leave it to you to show.

Comment: thank you for your thorough response! I understand now

Comment: No problem! Would you mind accepting it as an answer?